# Why is the GroupPolicy module not found even when RSAT is installed?

Tags: windows, powershell, group-policy, rsat

I'm trying to use the Get-GPO PowerShell module. So I installed RSAT first, but the GroupPolicy module is still missing:

```
PS C:\Users\admin\Desktop> Install-WindowsFeature RSAT

Success Restart Needed Exit Code      Feature Result
------- -------------- ---------      --------------
True    No             NoChangeNeeded {}


PS C:\Users\admin\Desktop> Import-Module grouppolicy
Import-Module : The specified module 'grouppolicy' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module
directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module grouppolicy
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (grouppolicy:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

PS C:\Users\admin\Desktop>
```

How do I install the GroupPolicy module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are very close. The Group Policy tools used to be installed as a subset of RSAT and I believe some documentation still states that.

Just run `Install-WindowsFeature GPMC` and you will get the Group Policy Management Console and the Group Policy PowerShell module installed.